# combine swf and jpg files in fla file

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

I have been asked to create an SWF file from a combination of images and existing swf files.

I have no issues putting the images into the timeline with motion/classic tweens to get them all into a nice smooth video. However, while I have been able to import the swf files to the library, I cannot seem to add them to the timeline!!

Do I have to work in actionscript or is there a simple way to drag the videos - each one lasts around 10 seconds.

Any help or guidance much appreciated.

Thanks!
JD

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way to do it using flash, but any other movie editor would be better for you, am i right?

Comment: I was hoping to do it simply in flash - but if there is another recommended open source programme I could use I am all ears!

Comment: I don't know a lot of programs that do it but, if you are using a mac, I think iMovie do it!